# My telegram auto message bot is working one time, how can I loop it?

Tags: python, time, telegram, telethon

hi i made a telegram auto-messaging bot using python but it only sends messages when i run it i need your help on how to loop it.

```
import sys
from telethon import TelegramClient
import time 
import datetime
starttime = time.time()

api_id = #api id
api_hash = '#api hash'

groups = ['#groups ']

failcount = 0;

while True:
    with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        for x in groups:
            try:
                client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message(x, '#message'))
            except:
                print(x, sys.exc_info()[0])
                failcount == 1
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), str(failcount/len(groups) * 100) + '%')
    time.sleep(10800 - ((time.time()- starttime) % 10800))
```

Comment: use default for loop

Answer (score 1):

that's obvious lmao delete all this and read the [docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/signing-in.html).

### you start a file like this:

import things you need

```
client = TelegramClient("session name", api_id, api_hash)

////////// code


client.run_until_disconnected()
```

to send a message use

```
@client.send_message('username or id', 'message')
```

oh and failcount should be += 1 (failcount = failcount + 1)

Answer (score 1):

You actually only need to make login once. Here is an working example:

```py
# Telethon
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, utils
import asyncio
import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(format='[%(levelname) 5s/%(asctime)s] %(name)s: %(message)s',
                    level=logging.WARNING)

api_id = '#api id'
api_hash = '#api hash'


client = TelegramClient('my_app', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    # Sending messages for myself
    i = 0;
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1);
        await client.send_message("me", f'Message - {i}')
        i += 1;
       

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The loop above will send messages forever, but, you can add `if else` to break the loop.

Comment: I want to ask one more thing, how do we wait for which group to message?

Comment: I didn't understood your question well... for waiting you can just use asyncio.sleep(your_time), and then use: "send_message" with the id of the group.

Comment: If you want to send messages when there is an specific event, you should look at [updates](https://telethonn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/basic/working-with-updates.html)